# Why GET method should use when we can user POST method for all type of methods?

Tags: api, post, get, webapi

I have some confusion that why we require GET methods when we can implement all methods with POST type.

Can you please share your thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given that GETs are read-only operations that don't modify the server's state, GETs are supposed to be "safe" activities. POSTs often experience state changes and issue warnings upon resubmission.